# Sum of the entries in the row of a 2D array within a java method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am currently enrolled in an online java class and my problem is as follows:

> Write a method `addRow` which has two parameters: a 2D array of doubles and an int. Return the sum of the entries in the row given by the second parameter. Return 0 if the row number is invalid. Do not assume that the number of rows and columns are the same.

My code for this question so far is as follows (I was only able to create the 2D array):

```java
int table[][] = new int[4][5];

table[0][0] = 0;
table[0][1] = 1;
table[0][2] = 2;
table[0][3] = 3;
table[0][4] = 4;

table[1][0] = 1;
table[1][1] = 2;
table[1][2] = 3;
table[1][3] = 4;
table[1][4] = 5;

table[2][0] = 1;
table[2][1] = 2;
table[2][2] = 3;
table[2][3] = 4;
table[2][4] = 5;

/*System.out.println table*/
```

Comment: I don't think the question says anything about creating a 2D array. You need to write a generic method to calculate the value of a random row. To write the method to add the values you're going to need these two tools: loops and array.length to check how many rows and to check the length of each row.

Comment: This is homework. You're supposed to actually give this a try, rather than cheating.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, your formed array is wrong as per your question. It mentions 2D array of `doubles` but you have chosen to define an 2D array of `int`

Your table should look like the following rather.

```
double table[][] = new double[4][5];
```

The question is pretty straightforward in itself. Create a function `addRow(double[][] array, int row)`

```
public static double addRow(double[][] array, int row) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  // check for valid input as row number
  if (row < array.length) {
      // iterate over all columns/cells of that row
      for (int i = 0; i < array[row].length; i++) {
           sum = sum + array[row][i];
      }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Most likely because you gave the answer to a homework problem. We try to give pointers and guide the students rather than feed them answers. Teach them to fish rather than give them the fish. Give them useful information that they can use to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: The definition of a downvote is the `answer is not useful`. The downvote is highly un necessary as per meta.stackexchange for answering. Over all, I feel  (& many others) feel answering a question helps the person really learn by knowing how it works than pushing the person in that direction. Not hoping to change any minds but definitely. I'll stick to my answer